# How to use count twice on same column in a table

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq

I've a table like below. What I want is to write a query which count all the rows where `exit_flag` is 0 and also count all the rows where `exit_flag` is 1 and than subtract the both counts and return a single value. How to do that using `entity framework`.

```
id created_date        device_id exit_flag
1  2017-10-24 23:00:00  13         0
2  2017-10-24 23:00:00  13         1
3  2017-10-24 23:30:00  13         0 
4  2017-10-24 23:30:00  13         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var answer = (from item in context.items
              group item by 0 into sub
              select 
              sub.Where(x => x.exit_flag == 0).Count() - sub.Where(x => x.exit_flag == 1).Count()
             ).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like below

```
select sum(exit_flag = 0),sum(exit_flag = 1),
sum(exit_flag = 0) - sum(exit_flag = 1)
from demo 
group by device_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8331b4/2)

> Using Mysql you can get your conditional count using sum function, When expression is used inside sum() it will return as boolean value 0/1

I have added group by device_id to get results per device if you want it for all the remove this part from query

Answer (score 1):

one way is wirite two different query to count exit_flag is 0 and exit_flag 1

1). `select count(*) as flg0 from table where exit_flag = 0;`

2). `select count(*) as flg1 from table where exit_flag = 1;`

and then substrect both value

and another

1). `select count(exit_flag = 0) - count(exit_flag = 1) as flg from table`